# SSRS 2005 Deployed / migrated reports do not fill browser

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I copied a prod SSRS server database and set it up as a dev SSRS server and reports seem to function fine, everything seems to work but the same reports are now in a small box in the browser instead of taking up the full browser.  Inspecting the page the ReportViewerControl takes up the whole page but the report window is a small fraction of that table.  In fact it's the table body within the table that the size is constrained.

I've compared the XML on the dev reports to the ones on the prod and they are the same.  The only modifications I made were datasources.  Is there something in IIS or SSRS that determines the size of the report table in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a browser issue with FireFox.